# Laravel Elequent/Query Builder return anonymous type with normal data

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

How can I return Sum and count with other data in laravel 5.4 query builder?
Suppose I have orders, orderDetails and Customers table. 
I want to return orderDetails list related to order and count of the row in oderDetails table.

```
id----customer-------totalorder-----totalAmount

2-----John--------------5------------2500
```

totalorder is the orderDetails table row count related to order id 2 and totalAmount is the sum of those 5 orders.

For the above output how can I make laravel query builder.

Comment: Don't use images to represent data.

Comment: i edited removing image. Thanks for your help. Can you help me out? @Troyer