# Laravel 5.4 Raw is not working as expected but working in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

```
 1. MySQL :      

        SELECT a.*,COUNT(DISTINCT  b.id)  AS IndianTruck,COUNT(DISTINCT  d.id) AS BdTruck

               FROM manifests a  
                JOIN truck_entry_regs b ON a.id = b.manf_id

                  LEFT JOIN truck_deliverys d ON a.id = d.manf_id

               WHERE a.manifest='550/7'
               GROUP BY a.id


2.Laravel 5.4 
   $results = DB::select('SELECT a.*, COUNT(DISTINCT  b.id)  AS IndianTruck,COUNT(DISTINCT  d.id) AS BdTruck

   FROM manifests a
    JOIN truck_entry_regs b ON a.id = b.manf_id

      LEFT JOIN truck_deliverys d ON a.id = d.manf_id

   WHERE a.manifest=?
   GROUP BY a.id', ['550/7'])
```

I have the same query.
The first query run well on MySQL(Sqlyog). But if i run (second query ) it on  my laravel 5.4 app it says:

```
   QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dbblpa.a.port_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT a.*, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS IndianTruck,COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) AS BdTruck

FROM manifests a
JOIN truck_entry_regs b ON a.id = b.manf_id

LEFT JOIN truck_deliverys d ON a.id = d.manf_id

WHERE a.manifest=550/7
GROUP BY a.id)
```

How can i return all data from a table with cont from other tables after joining?
If i add a.id,a.name in the select (like select a.id,a.name, COUNT(DISTINCT  b.id)) and add a.id and a.name in  GROUP BY , then it works.
The question if i return all column from a table with count should i add all column in group by? I know it is odd!
Then how can i get my expected result in laravel 5.4 query builder?

Comment: Is `manifests .id` the primary key? Or at least unique?

Comment: It is primary key. But I did not make  foreign key with truck_deliverys or truck_entry_regs explicitly.

Comment: FKs do not matter for this issue.

Comment: Then what causes the issue?

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not notice that you are the same man! I read it but haven't tried yet. Let you know if it works and will vote you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do this using query builder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137892/discussion-between-paul-spiegel-and-fawel).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699154/laravel-elequent-query-builder-return-annonymous-type-with-normal-data

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.3 and 5.4 use strict mode for mysql per default. That means that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is also enabled. But if your MySQL version is at least 5.7.5 you can group by a primary key of a table and use all columns from that table in the SELECT clause because they are functionally dependent on the PK.

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before
>   5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default.

([MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html))

Your options are:

Upgrade MySQL to at least 5.7.5

Or disable strict mode in laravels db config (`config/database.php`)

```
// ..
'connections' => [
    // ..
    'mysql' => [
        // ..
        'strict' => false,
        // ..
    ],
    // ..
]
```

**Update**

Bad news for MariaDB (and xampp) user: MariaDB seems not to support the "detection of functional dependence" (yet). All i could  find is this [ticket](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11588).

Comment: I am using - MySql '5.1.58-community' (result of SELECT VERSION()). It works . I changed   'strict' => false,