# MySQL query runs in phpMyAdmin, not in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.*, Count(b.status) as counttotal 
FROM holidays a LEFT JOIN attendances b 
on a.month_id=b.month_id 
GROUP BY a.month_id
```

This query successfully executes in phpMyAdmin.

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot here]

When I tried to run the same query through `php artisan tinker`, I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'school_blog.a.month' isn't in
>   GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT a.*, Count(b.status) as counttotal FROM holidays
>   a LEFT JOIN attendances b on a.month_id=b.month_id GROUP BY
>   a.month_id)'

How do I fix this?

[image: check the screen shot of erroe msg]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42747612/899126) may solve your issue

Answer (score 3):

Go to your config/database.php and change the following "true" to "false"  so it looks like below

```
'mysql' => [

    'strict' => false,

]
```